# How to create our own image dataset for cnn

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data, image-classification

I have two different  folders containing my images and random images how to spilit it to train and test in  a cnn model

I tried to spilt it as training data and testing data but i dont know how to do it.I need to know what is the process to build our own dataset from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're only asking how to split your images in train & test, here's how you can do it:

```
import os
import shutil
import random

# Define paths for source and destination folders
source_folder = 'path/to/source_folder'  # Replace with your source folder path
train_folder = 'path/to/train_folder'    # Replace with your train folder path
test_folder = 'path/to/test_folder'      # Replace with your test folder path

# Define the ratio for splitting (e.g., 80% train, 20% test)
train_ratio = 0.8

# Create destination folders if they don't exist
os.makedirs(train_folder, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(test_folder, exist_ok=True)

# List all image files in the source folder
image_files = [file for file in os.listdir(source_folder) if file.endswith(('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'))]

# Shuffle the list to randomize the selection
random.shuffle(image_files)

# Calculate the number of files for training
train_count = int(len(image_files) * train_ratio)

# Split files into train and test sets
train_images = image_files[:train_count]
test_images = image_files[train_count:]

# Move images to the respective folders
for image in train_images:
    src_path = os.path.join(source_folder, image)
    dst_path = os.path.join(train_folder, image)
    shutil.copyfile(src_path, dst_path)

for image in test_images:
    src_path = os.path.join(source_folder, image)
    dst_path = os.path.join(test_folder, image)
    shutil.copyfile(src_path, dst_path)
```

P.S. You would still have to have your data labeled for different classes, with proper annotation format according to your CNN model. Also, this is just spliting your data into train-test directory, not reading your images to feed into your model.